# Is there anything about Spiritual Awakening or Kundalini or Ascension in Islam?

Tags: sufism

Salam All,

Is there any mention of Spiritual Awakening or Kundalini or Ascension in ISLAM?
Does Quran state anything about it? And Also is it HADITH?

From spiritual awakening I mean the thing which is stated in following links:

http://www.ascensionsymptoms.com/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kundalini

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I want to establish that Islam is not a religion of superstitions. We concern ourselves with the divine only when it is explicitly explained to us in the Quran or the Hadith.

There is the concept of a spirit/soul in Islam. Every person has a soul inside of him, but we know very little about it and can never know any more:

> وَيَسأَلونَكَ عَنِ الرّوحِ ۖ قُلِ الرّوحُ مِن أَمرِ رَبّي وَما أوتيتُم مِنَ العِلمِ إِلّا قَليلًا
>
> And they ask you, [O Muhammad], about the soul. Say, "The soul is of the affair of my Lord. And mankind have not been given of knowledge except a little. (17:85)

So, we know very little about the nature of the soul, and that is all we need to know.

In Islam, there is no evidence to support any concepts of spiritual awakenings or ascension. The only way to help your soul is to worship Allah in the ways that the Prophet (SAW) did: praying, reading Quran, fasting, etc.

And as a conclusion, I will remind that the Prophet (SAW) never mentioned any such thing, and there is no evidence in the Quran. If it (as a spiritual concept) had any truth to it then Allah and his messenger would have said something.

Answer (score 3):

*I should first thank you for bringing up a comparative religion question. I believe these questions help us broaden our perspective and eliminate the "all-other-religions-are-totally-wrong" mentality that occupies the minds of average followers of religions, and open up our eyes upon a lot of valuable spiritual wisdom that all world religions, even the non-Abrahamic ones, share.*

At the first glance, there's obviously no explicit mentioning or discussion of Kundalini system in Quran or Hadith, especially if you are looking for exact verbally identical common concepts. However, there exists *substantial* and *remarkable* commonalities in terms of *spiritual experiences*, *mental states* and *moral/practical virtues* that are discussed and celebrated in Kundalini Yoga and Islamic Sufism and Irfan.

Many followers of Islamic Sufism and Irfan both claim to be founded upon and trace their origins to Quran and Hadiths of the Holy Prophet and his companions. As for claims of Sufism take a look at the this [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufism), and as for Irfan a more distinctly Shiite version of Islamic Mysticism take a look at [this chapter](http://www.al-islam.org/al-tawhid/vol4-n1/introduction-irfan-ayatullah-murtadha-mutahhari/origins-islamic-irfan) from Morteza Mutahhari's introductory book on Irfan.

As you study, learn and and practice Irfan or Sufism, you just can't miss so many references to spiritual states and conditions that also find expression in Indian/eastern mysticisms, albeit often through different terminologies.

There are actually a lot of comparative studies made to identify these commonalities. Here's an [example](http://www.meditationexpert.com/comparative-religion/c_islamic_meditation_and_moslem_spiritual_methods.htm) and an excerpt therefrom:

> In Islam, "seeing the Tao" is called "seeing God's face." The
>   kundalini phenomenon is called "the fire of separation" in Islam
>   whereas yoga calls it the "gastric fire" or "kundalini," Taoism calls
>   it the "clumsy fire," Tibetans call it the "tumo heat," and
>   Christianity calls it "incendium amoris."

I recommend you to follow up studying this topic, as its the most fascinating and enlightening topic as to the essence of world religions. Yet, I also do find it necessary to remind you that you should keep a critical mind through all along, because especially when it comes to some cosmological beliefs such as the existence of deities or the doctrine of reincarnation, Islam and Eastern Mysticisms may widely diverge.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any mention of Spiritual Awakening or Kundalini or Ascension in Islam?

According to Ayatollah Khomeini in a discussion of hadith, the direct apprehension of divine reality is the preserve of the prophets and not of the ordinary man; this is why they - the prophets - don't suffer from spiritual doubt; after all, how can anyone deny what has been experienced directly - but the ordinary man often does.

Moreover, according to Ibn al-Arabi, although the Prophet Muhammed is the 'Seal of Prophets' there are lower grades of spiritual attainment; for example, there is the notion of *wali*, translated into English often as saint but is commonly understood as friends of the divine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes at lot of places Quran mentions about the process, which if you correlate, do resembles what the process of Kundalini is.

Surah Al-Bakarah - states when Allah made prophet Adam (PBUH), Allah blew his energy in him, which we all carry at the base of the spine.

Surah Tin - states about the human body which is the perfect design. Also, this surah describes the awakening help with some pure foods and the secure environment (city).

Surah Al-Hadid - mentions about people of heaven when questioned about the light, they will respond to people of hell to look at the back, which is the basis of Kundalini.

Quran states, Allah keeps a record of what have been send and what is left behind. This is about the energy.

Also Surah A'ala states the same description have already been given to the earliest revelation, also mentioned in the books of prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) and prophet Musa (PBUH).

There are good and solid references in Quran, if we understand. Allah made everything in pairs, even at electron level and energy. Kundalini energy has polarity.

I believe that Allah have the same rules for all the humans from the beginning to the end. I encourage everyone to understand the meaning of Ar-Rahmanhir-Raheem. There is no injustice from Allah's side to anyone.

I have more details which are mind blowing. Our prophet Muhammad (PBUH) made the process very simple which is applicable to any human. If followed the success is sure. That is why prophet Muhammad (PBUH) came for the entire mankind.

We don't understand the simple aspects but argue on complicated matters. Surah Al-Fatiha if repeated with faith your Kundalini will awake and rise. There are tons of aspects Islam teaches which are perfect, simple to follow and will definitely make the person successful in the life after. Kundalini process makes you successful in the Aakhirat.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. Please provide the sources of the interpretation of the Qur'an that you have in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Adding on to some of the brilliant comments here, 
Let's take a look at what's taking place in Ascension circles around the planet.

Take what you know about isra wa al-miraj and apply it to what you know of the 7 chakras which are directly connected to states of consciousness. And so the 7 heavens. Each heaven is higher than the other. And the 7th which is highest the crown chakra relates to your own divinity and is connected to jannatul Firdaus.

The Prophet SAW said that there will be those who will be put on a bridge between dunya and jannah, so that they could purify their hearts before entering jannah. That's exactly where we are. We are in that state of limbo where we have to purify our hearts before we enter the 5th dimension which constitutes the beginning of the higher realms.

If you've heard of Twin flames, you know of the verses that say "We created you in pairs". Surah 51:59 and Surah 78:9. We were literally created in pairs. The masculine soul and the feminine soul before we incarnated into the planet.

You've heard people saying that our bodies are changing from carbon based to crystalline based DNA and physical form. Remember when the Prophet SAW was telling of the way the people injannahwill have such clear skin that they will see water flowing into people's guts. And we will not pass out waste from our bodies, nor will women have their monthly flows, because the crystalline based body is already purified and will not need more purification.

When you read Suratul Zilzalah, what of it do you see happening right now? All the way from the turn of the millenium, global warming, hurricanes, typhoons, earthquakes, volcanic eruptions,... Literally, mother earth is spewing out all the negative energy humanity has been feeding her for ages. And check out how many angels are flocking to earth. Some of us can't see them but some can. 
And there's a reason for their coming.

So although some people don't want to agree, yes, in Islam we also have tons of messages and information about the Ascension. It's happening in our lifetime.

Answer (score -2):

No , i mean yes but not like that. The awekening quran talks about is at the time people were being sold as slaves women had no rights they were like property when some man died his however many wives could be transferred like the rest of his property people had to work as slaves and their wives and daughters were sold as sex slaves to pay his debt people were dying from hunger while rich  was getting enormously richer little girls were being buried alive quran came at those times to put an end to that sadly these things are still happening but people have free will people are gonna do what they do well as a good muslim we need to stand up for what's right. Wake up and see these things and fight to stop them to make the world a better place to start from yourself to give, love ,be patient, live in harmony, pray, restraint yourself , have strong will, fight against your ego etc etc... this is the awakening of the bottom line people the rise of a movement and act of rebellion to live free ...

Comment: I miss a real relation to the question asked!